# Multiple occurrences of each capturing group in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the tables and aliases of a SQL select statement, for example the following select:

```
select * from table1 t1, table2, table3 t3, table4 where column = 1
```

should return two capturing groups, the first one `table1`, `table2`, `table3` and `table4`. The second capturing group `t1`, null, `t3` and null.

My attempt returns only the first item of each capturing group:

```
from\s+([^ ,]+)\s*(\w+)*,
```

returns `table1` and `t1` only. How to expand the regex to retrieve all the occurrences?

Comment: I don't see how the question you're proposing as dup answers my question

Comment: @pgschr: The solution you get is also match, then split by delimiter. So it's more or less a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **`str` is your string**

```
var tables = str.match(/from\s(.*)\swhere/)[1].split(/, /);
```

Returns:

```
["table1 t1", "table2", "table3 t3", "table4"]
```

Comment: I need to relate the alias to the table name, for example table3 with t3, in your Regex I cannot do that

Comment: @pgschr ah, that's even easier. I'll update my answer